# Actionscript 3 Timer on click hold

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent

I have a function where I need to click and cube once and the cube will rotate to that side, then when i click and hold  for 2 seconds will go to fifth page or when i click with no hold will start the cube rotating.

This is what I have

```
var numPressed:Number = 0
    function side6(event:MouseEvent):void {
        numPressed++;
            if (numPressed % 2) {
                SimpleZSorter.sortClips(container);
                TweenLite.to(container, 1, {rotationX:-8,rotationY:193});
                addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateStop);
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateThis);
            }else if (NEED SOEMTHING HERE TO DETECT MOSUE HOLD AFTER SECONDS) {
                gotoAndStop(5);
            }
            else{
                addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rotateThis);
            }
    }
```

The idea atm is numpressed calculates if the presses are odd or even, meaning 1 click will stop the cube rotating, 2 will start it again, a third will stop if and so forth, i need this to keep acting like that.

I need something in the second if statement, everything works well apart from getting it to work on holding the mouse.

Any help appreciated

Ian

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `MouseEvent.DOWN` and `MouseEvent.UP` and store `Date.time` for this.

EG: This set of functions would track the ammount of millisenconds elapsed between the MouseEvent.DOWN and the MouseEvent.UP event.

```
private var mouseDownTime:Number = NaN,mouseUpTime:Number = NaN;

private function init():void
{
    yourCubeObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOWN,onMouseDown);
    yourCubeObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.UP,onMouseUp);
    yourCubeObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.OUT,onMouseOut);
}
private function onMouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    mouseDownTime = mouseUpTime = NaN;//clear storage
}
private function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    mouseDownTime = new Date().time;//store system time in milliseconds since epoc
}
private function onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    mouseUpTime = new Date().time;
    if (!isNaN(mouseDownTime))//avoid error case where mouse went down outside object
    {
        if ((mouseUpTime - mouseDownTime) >= 2000)
        {
            //mouse held down for more the 2 seconds, your function here.
        }
    }
    onMouseOut(event);//reset counters
}
```